# Ubuntu cannot detect NVIDIA GPU for dual GPU comp

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, gpu-driver

I have dual boot (windows & ubuntu) laptop (Thinkpad P15v) which contains contains two GPU's. One being intel iris xe and the other being Nvidia RTX 2000. Unfortunately the drivers for Nvidia doesnt appear under software updates (Software Updates -> settings -> Additional Drivers) and I get "No addtional drivers available".

When I check further with following commands from other posts I get the following in the teminal.

`sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA`

> VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:46a6] (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

`lspci | grep 3D`

> 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107GLM [RTX A2000 Mobile] (rev a1)

`lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d"`

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
> 01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107GLM [RTX A2000 Mobile] (rev a1)

`nvidia-smi`

> zsh: command not found: nvidia-smi

It seems for some reason ubuntu cannot recognize the NVIDIA GPU. Any idea how I can install this?